# When comparing two Hex values, if one is shorter than the other, what do I fill in for the shorter?

Tags: byte, bit

Sorry for the confusing title if it doesn't make much sense.
I'm somewhat new to systems and C in general, so when it comes to bits/bytes/hex, I'm on the sidelines trying to figure it out.

My question is that if I have an order of bytes, lets say:

0x01020304 and I want to use the & logical operator with 0xFF, what bytes in the former am I comparing FF to since it's a much shorter byte?

I think I remember that the MSB's are moved to the right, as in FF, and then filled in with 0's on the left so that the 0s are compared with 0x010203, where FF would compare with 04.

Am I correct in thinking this or do I fill in this comparison another way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: 
0xFF is the same as 0x000000FF.

So...

```
  int f1 = 0x01020304; (16909060 in decimal)
  int f2 = 0x000000ff; (255 in decimal)
  int f3 = f1&f2; (gives us 4 in decimal)
```

same with this code:

```
  int f1 = 0x01020304; (16909060 in decimal)
  int f2 = 0xff; (255 in decimal)
  int f3 = f1&f2; (gives us 4 in decimal)
```

Hope that helps.

In other words: Yup, you're right with your considerations.

Comment: It's the same as decimal. For instance, 42 is the same as 0000042. You wouldn't ask, "If I am adding 49152 + 1, what digit do I add the 1 to?"

Comment: @Hubert Popiolkiewicz Except nobody uses octal anymore. ;-)

Comment: @JohnSensebe To be exact, people passing OCJP exams must get to know with octal literals. Just sayin', worth mentioning.